# The row before Nav bar is not visible in bootstrap html

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add the  row before the nav bar, but after adding the row , it is not visible  and the rows is covered by nav bar. How can I show the row   before the Nav bar

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class=row>
        The text is not visible here
    </div>
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark-header fixed-top" id="main-nav">
            <div class="w-100 d-flex">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-md-auto" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="80px" width="auto">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="img/Logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:250px;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyCompany</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Privacy">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Privacy">Our Project</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Privacy">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-light" style="position: fixed;">
        The text is not visible here
</div>
```

you have to add a position to that div because it's overlaps with that header.

Answer (score 0):

Class `fixed-top` is add to the `nav element` which sticks the navigating at top, and hides the above `.row` element.

1. You can Either remove the `fixed-top` class from navigation, if you dont need top fixed navigation
2. Add the `.row element` inside the navigation, which will fix the row at top of the navigation

Comment: Please can you give me an example